# Home brew Apache error_log child pid * exit signal Floating point exception (8) on mac osx 10.11 AMP stack

Tags: macos, apache, drupal-7, homebrew

every time a enable a module in Drupal 7, refresh the page, i get this

- This page isn’t working
- localhost didn’t send any data.
- ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

my local dev is homebrew's Apache2.4, php7 on a mac osx 10.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching back to homebrew's php56 solved this, and now i don't have any SIGFPE in my apache logs. Now i can enable any Druapl7 module, and works like charm!.

Problem: Yes, i had homebrew's php71, i think Maybe one of the php scripts is broken, either by design or a subtly corrupt file hence getting apache logging SIGFPE ("exit signal Floating point exception (8)")

You can install sphp to switch from php71 back and forth to php56. click here to read about [sphp](https://gist.github.com/w00fz/142b6b19750ea6979137b963df959d11)